# Visual Basic - Changing Button Color using a loop

Tags: .net, vb.net, loops, user-interface

For practice I am writing a VB application which simulates and elevator system with 4 elevators and 40 floors in the building - when a button is pressed I want it to change color until the elevator reaches that floor.

Currently the only way I can think of to do this is by hard-coding a check which looks through the list of destination floors that each lift has and if it contains a given floor change the color of that button like this:

```
' button 1
        If elevator1.goingUpList.Contains(1) Or elevator1.goingDownList.Contains(1) Then
            lift1Button1.BackColor = Color.LightGoldenrodYellow
        ElseIf (elevator1.goingUpList.Contains(1) = False) Or (elevator1.goingDownList.Contains(1) = False) Then
            lift1Button1.BackColor = DefaultBackColor
        End If
```

The problem is with this is that I would have to do it for each button (40 in total) of each of the 4 elevators - 160 times essential 960 lines to do a fairly simple task. THere must be an easier way?

I was thinking a loop that goes through the elevators lists , retrieving each floor that is in the list could be an easier solution - but how would I get the corresponding button to change color?

Comment: start by dynamically generating your interface.  that will give you programmatic access to each button without having to hard code your control IDs or hard coding your controls to an array that you can loop over.  Once you do that, your possibilities open up.

Comment: the 40 elevator buttons can either share a common procedure or you can call 1 or 2 procedures like Elevator, ElevatorUp and ElevatorDown from the buttons, OR both

Comment: Reduce your problem down to 3 floors and 3 elevators. Solve it, increase to 5 floors and 4 elevators. See if it still works. If not, adjust. Notice the pattern, replace with 40 floors and you're done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can use `For Each` loop for your buttons. Windows Forms have the `Controls` `Collection` property. Every control such as `Button`, `Label` and `TextBox` are added to that `Contorls` `Collection` unless you are using `Panel`, `GroupBox` or other containers.

By using `For Each` loop in `Me.Controls`, all type of controls will be going through. So you have to check for the type of control with `TypeOf` operator.

If your form has other buttons rather than "Elevator buttons", you need to set `Tag` property of your "Elevator buttons" to "1" or elevator number.

Here is the sample code

```
Dim ctl As Object
Dim elevatorNumber As String
Dim buttonNumber As String

For Each ctl In Me.Controls
    If TypeOf ctl Is Button Then
        elevatorNumber = ctl.Tag
        buttonNumber = ctl.Text

        If elevatorNumber = "1" Then
            If elevator1.goingUpList.Contains(buttonNumber) Or elevator1.goingDownList.Contains(buttonNumber) Then
                ctl.BackColor = Color.LightGoldenrodYellow
            ElseIf (elevator1.goingUpList.Contains(buttonNumber) = False) Or (elevator1.goingDownList.Contains(buttonNumber) = False) Then
                ctl.BackColor = DefaultBackColor
            End If
        End If

    End If
Next
```